# If $\tau_1=(a\space b), \tau_2=(c\space d)$, why is $\tau_1\tau_2=(d\space a\space c\space )(a\space b\space d)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For two permutations $\tau_1=(a\space b), \tau_2=(c\space d)$, why is $\tau_1\tau_2=(d\space a\space  c\space )(a\space b\space d)? \text{ (where }a,b,c,d \text{ are all distinct)}.$

I'm fairly new to group theory, so I apologize if this is an obvious result. Here's my attempt:

$\tau_1\tau_2=(a\space b)(c\space d)=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\
b&a&c&d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\
a&b&d&c
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d&\\
b&a&d&c
\end{bmatrix}$

but I'm not sure how to write this as $(d\space a\space  c\space )(a\space b\space d)$.

Thanks.

Comment: $(d\space a\space c)(a\space b\space d)=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\
c&b&d&a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\
b&d&c&a
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d&\\
b&a&d&c
\end{bmatrix} = \tau_1\tau_2$.

Comment: @Krish, that is an answer

Comment: @EricStucky did I miss something?? Sorry, but I didn't get you.

Comment: @Krish: I think Eric meant you can post what you wrote in your comment as a solution below. Also, I was wondering: From $(a\space b)(c\space d)$, is there a way to tell right away that it is equal to $(d\space a \space c)(a\space b \space d)$ without expanding both sides?

Comment: @Sujaan Kunalan a permutation of $n$ elements can be think of a bijection on the set $\{ 1, 2, \cdots, n\}$ and product of permutation means just composition of functions. if we write $f = (a \space b), g = (c \space d)$ and $p = (d \space a \space c), q = (a \space b \space d)$, then basically we want to prove that $fg = pq$. so we can evaluate both the side at each of the points $a, b, c, d$ and try to see whether these two functions are equal or not. for example, $a \xrightarrow{q} b \xrightarrow{p} b$ and $a \xrightarrow{g} a \xrightarrow{f}b$. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As Krish mentions, you can just multiply out $(d\quad a\quad c)(a\quad b\quad d)$ to see that it is indeed equal to $(a\quad b)(c\quad d)$. There isn't usually a way to "see" what the product is as a composition of disjoint cycles, except for a few examples. One common example is a decomposition of the permutation $(1\quad 2\quad\cdots\quad n)$ into the transpositions
$$
(1\quad n)(1 \quad n-1)\cdots(1\quad 3)(1\quad 2)
$$
which is easily recognised.

It is important to remember that permutations are not written uniquely. There are many ways of writing the same permutation: consider, for example, the identity permutation $e$. This can be written as $(1\quad 2)(2\quad 1)$, or as $(1\quad 2\quad 3)(1\quad 3\quad 2)$, or a whole bunch of other ways. The example in your question is one common way to rewrite a product of disjoint transpositions which is helpful for proving key premutation results, such as [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788604/clarification-needed-regarding-why-identity-can-be-written-only-as-a-product-of).